# ListView with Multiple Headers and Details Sections

Tags: android

Can we have a listview that has different sections means
Header
details

Header
Details

As we scrollup the Header gets Fixed and the details scroll till the next Header comes.

As I can say
Courses
then a list of courses.when last course comes then comes
Heading Cities
then a list of cities
Heading Batch Timings
then a list of timings.

when using ListView with different Headers and Details I am able to show the Sections Header and Details but I can't fix the Header and then scroll the details till next Header comes.
kindly update if there is any such component to do it

Answer (score -1):

This [PinnedHeadListView project](https://github.com/chenjishi/PinnedHeadListView) i have found in github .
It provides headers to listview and expandablelistview.